# iOS11 bug - TableView with searchBar jumps back after scrolling up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem with iOS11 with the UISearchController search results tableView, which contains a few cells. I scroll the tableView up, then I finish scrolling and remove my finger from the screen. After that, the tableView must scroll down to the borders to show all available cells. But the scrolling is frozen for 0.5 seconds instead and then tableView jumps back very strong and quickly. It looks too bad.

The Search bar lies on the navigation bar. 
While I scroll, any code is not executed because all cells remain in the scope of the screen. I put breakpoints to each controller function, but they do not work.

I recorded a video about this error. The video is available at: https://youtu.be/g3LqdpI4FeA

How can I fix it?

Comment: As per the video you don’t have many cells for the table view to scroll. Can you add 30 cells and try

Comment: Yes I can. After that it works, but it has to work with a few cells because search results can contain a few cells and even only one.

Comment: @aktubuct can you try it on real device not in a simulator?

Comment: @Martin I observe this bug on both, on the simulator and on the real device

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue. The bug exist because tableView tries to scroll cells including searchBar while searchBar is active and held on the top of the screen by itself.

The solution is to force change value navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling to false while searchBar is active and return it back when searchBar is closing.

```
func willPresentSearchController(_: UISearchController) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
}

func willDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
}
```